# Receiving JSON parameter contains ${} cause error in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

When the JSON I received the request contains ${}, the ${} is removed from the received object.

requested JSON

```
{
  "name":"$123$",
  "str1":"${str1}",
  "str2":"${str222",
  "str3":"${str3}333",
  "str4":"${str4}44444"
}
```

Controller

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping("std")
    public Std test$2(@RequestBody Std std) {
        return std;
    }
}
```

Std.java

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Std {
    private String name;
    private String str1;
    private String str2;
    private String str3;
    private String str4;
    private String aa;
}
```

Result

```
{
"name": "$123$",
"str1": "str1",
"str2": "${str222",
"str3": "str3333",
"str4": "str444444"
}
```

When I manually parse JSON through code, the result is correct. The output JSON contains ${}.
like this

```java
    public void test() {
        try {
            String str = "{\n" +
                    "  \"name\":\"$123$\",\n" +
                    "  \"str1\":\"${str1}\",\n" +
                    "  \"str2\":\"${str2}22\",\n" +
                    "  \"str3\":\"${str3}333\",\n" +
                    "  \"str4\":\"${str4}44444\"\n" +
                    "}";
            Std std = JSON.parseObject(str, Std.class);
            System.out.println(JSON.toJSONString(std));
            Std std1 = objectMapper.readValue(str, Std.class);
            System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(std1));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There is no additional configuration for Jackson in the project

Answer (score 1):

The `${variableName}` notation is used in Spring Boot for the purpose of importing the values of configuration variables or environment variables. This is the root cause for the issue shown above.

**The problem can be fixed in 2 ways -**

1. Replace ${ and } with a different de-limiter character

   Example:  Use `#data#` instead of `${data}`

   This approach is easy to implement as it can be done with small code change.
2. Add an explicit escape sequence for the closing brace, I.E., for **}** character in the input JSON.

   This approach is difficult to implement, as it it may require more code changes than  the other approach.

Comment: Does the second way mean JSON value should like this `${data\}`?

Comment: Hi Agstar, Yes. \} can be used for escaping the closing brace '}'.